# What is the best way to make a simple Perl config file?

Tags: perl, configuration-files

I am trying to make a simple config file for my Perl script, I originally was going to use [Config::INIPlus](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aINIPlus) but I don't think it is going to work. The config file does not need to be anything special. I just need to be able to read and write to it. I would like to use a module to accomplish this.

Update:

The reason I don't think Config::INIPlus will work for me might sound stupid, but I want to have the config file maintain a specific order of values. The problem I keep running into is the Config::INIPlus module insists on erasing the entire file and then reinserting all of the values in alphabetical order regardless of there subject they pertain to so it messes up the order which I would like to keep the config file ordered. Also it erases my empty variables that I had left for place holders.

I had made a test of my idea using registry as the config storage and it was great! The problem is though I am trying to make my script a platform independent as possible mainly Windows and Linux not so much Mac as I don't own one.

Maybe I just need to rethink my view on the config file maybe I am ask for something that cannot be done until I grasp more the finer points of perl.

Comment: If you happen to have the book Perl Best Practices lying around somewhere, I believe it has a whole section on config file loading and saving.

Comment: Could you explain why you think Config::INIPlus isn't going to work for you?  Are you running into bugs?  Do you not like its config format?

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for something simple, I'd try [Config::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aTiny) or [Config-INI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-INI/).

What I don't like about [Config::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aSimple) is that it tries to support too many different config formats.

Neither YAML nor JSON nor XML is what I would call a "simple" config file, although they are suitable if you have more complex requirements.  I would avoid XML if at all possible; at `$WORK` I wrote a YAML-to-XML config-file-translator so I could write my config in YAML instead of hand-editing XML config files.

**Update for updated question:**  It's certainly possible to write a Config module that preserves the order of existing lines, but I'm not aware of any existing one that does that.  You'd probably have to write your own, or hire someone to write it.

Comment: Huh I was not aware of Config-INI, I have had my run in with Config::Tiny already it actually messed up config file I had written in INI syntax and dropped it! I will look into Config-INI it might be exactly what I need.

Comment: @Solignis, Config-INI was derived from Config::Tiny, so you may have the same issue.  You should update your question with more details about what you've tried and what went wrong, so we can give better advice.  If the problem is that comments get stripped, you may need to write a new Config module, because I don't know of any that can accurately round-trip comments.

Comment: +1 Anything *but* `YAML`, `JSON`, or `XML` for a simple human-editable config file.

Comment: @cjm - what's wrong with XML config files? They are VERY human readable (especially if you read them in any software able to syntax highlight them like a programming editor; or better yet in a browser!), and pretty easily human maintainable; and there are CPAN modules which support them.

Comment: @Sinan - what's wrong with XML? (JSON is not that bad for humans but not as easy as XML).

Comment: What's wrong with XML? `<option name="myapp:settings:edit:this:that:other" type="integer" guid="xxx-yyyy-zzzz-xyxy-yzyz-zxxz-zzzz-xxxx"><name>other</name><value>bob</value></option>` because someone thought it was OK to generate XML by string concatenation and a straightforward mapping would have been too meaningful. Or, even, http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Extensible-XML.aspx

Answer (score 1):

YAML? JSON? XML? there are many possibilities, each with a Perl module. There's also plain old text, but if you must use a module, just pick a standard.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help I will have to make tests of each kind and see which one suites me best. Do they each have a strength and weakness or are they all about the same?

Comment: YAML is simpler than JSON is simpler than XML. All equally powerful IMO.

Comment: so someone like who is still learning the basics of perl YAML may be the way to go?

Comment: YAML is unfortunately the one I know least about. I'm having to use it for one of my clients' projects. but I'm guessing that's a yes.

Comment: YAML is both simpler and more complex than JSON.  In terms of the things it can store and the complete specification, it's quite a bit more complex than JSON.  It's simpler only in that a YAML file _can_ contain much less extraneous punctuation than a JSON file (which requires strings to be quoted).

Answer (score 1):

What about [`Config::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aSimple)?  There are some related modules too.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I do like [Config::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config%3a%3aSimple) and it was very useful to me in a few projects, my favorite is [AppConfig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/AppConfig).